# How to see the current progress of a long running C# async operation using VS2017?

Tags: c#

For a long running C# async operation, how can we see the current progress of the operation using VS2017? Can VS2017 or any plugin achieve this?

I have a long running complex async operation which starts in a WinForms button click, there are a lot of levels of async calls in the operation.Now the operation seems "stuck", and I want to find the place it "stuck" at. I don't want to modify the code to output the progress, only want to use some debugging tools that is "async aware".

Comment: if you are running it in the debugger, then you can always break in by pressing `Alt+Ctrl+Break` or clicking the `Break All` button on `Debug` menu. Then you can inspect the stack trace and threads window, to find out what is going on

Comment: Break all won't work because it will break at the WinForms main loop.

Comment: Yes, and that's when you can inspect the current state of your code in `Watch Window`. There is no automatic way to know the progress you have made in your code, as the definition of progress depends on your own code. You might want to put in some logging to log the progress, but again that would need code change

Comment: When you debug a normal program that stuck, you break all and know everything instantly from call stack, you don't need to write any code. That's what I want for async code which have a definite running progress (like a call stack) at any time and that's what I want VS to tell me (insntantly) .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your tools to be "async aware" - they are code aware and it's enough. Just put your breakpoints where you see fit in your methods and hit Debug. Nothing will pass through those breakpoints.

Or you can break at any point by clicking on the pause button (Break All). But this has nothing to do with async. It's simply debugging.

As to debugging multiple threads, check out [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d36e03c8-114f-4cce-a336-280c59a66afe/how-to-debug-the-async-methods-).

Comment: My need is to see the current progress which has nothing to do with setting break point. Yes, break all won't work because it will break at the WinForms main loop.

Comment: Is this some sort of a test question?  In your original question you say: "Now the operation seems "stuck", and I want to find the place it "stuck" at". Tou can achieve that by setting breakpoints around your calls starting from the topmost ones and narrowing down to the problematic call. That's called debugging. Now you're talking about "progress" which has nothing to do with the problem and debugging. You can also break all and it will stop everything (break ALL) not only your "main loop".

Comment: We can always debug some problem by setting break points around the potential problematic code and by add a lot of log around it. But advanced tools can save our time to find the place instantly. Some examples are break all to find a deadlock point, you don't need to set any break point or add any log to find it. The question made it clear to ask for advanced tools instead of the above ways to find  the "stuck" for an ongoing async operation. Here obviously "stuck point"  means the progress of the async operation.

Answer (score 0):

If break points aren't an option, your best bet is probably some form of logging. You could log pertinent information to a file or the Windows Event Log. This way your process would still be running, but you could "see" what your process is doing.